# autoloading third party libraries on codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a CI application that I am testing on three different environments :

Locally (XAMPP)
Shared hosting (Godaddy)
VPS (linode)

I am using the same files for all versions.

I figured out that on my VPS there is a library that is not autoloading, I have a blank page when I load the web application when the library is on autoload. When I load it in a controller separately it works. but i need it autoloaded.

On my localhost as well as the shared hosting, it is working perfectly.

I turned the mode to development to spot error, turned errors to on, I still have the blank page and no error log

Do you think it is a configuration on the VPS ? something I should do ?

I searched a lot before asking, all similar problems are related to the database library and not third party ones

Any ideas ?

Thank you

**EDIT**

In case it happens to anyone, I was missing a library on my server (cURL) so make sure you have all needed ressources on your server

Comment: The library in question probably uses a PHP extension that's not available on your VPS.

Comment: That's it I just figured out.